# Does test credentials require to give to Google play for view while uploading apk without sign page to

Tags: android, google-play

I am uploading an application on play store which don't have any sign up page in mobile application. Do I need to give any test credentials while uploading apk on google play store for reviewing purpose. In iOS we certainly need to share credentials I am just confirming does any sort of requirement exist on google play end or not ?

Answer (score 1):

NO,there is no requirement exist on google play end like this.
But,yes this will be problematic for real user if any are there.